# how to lock global variable in multi thread?

Tags: c#

I  have two thread ,Each running two threads, no error appear. but run together,the  backgroundWorker2 tip :can't clone null.....(I check variable J value is greater than 100),in this case,how to lock global variable?

```
Bitmap img; //global variable
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"i:\1.jpg");
            img.Dispose();
            i++;
            backgroundWorker3.ReportProgress(i,"");
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        } while (!backgroundWorker4.CancellationPending);
    }

 private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int j= 0;
        do
        {
            //img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"i:\1.jpg");

            if (img != null)
            {
                lock (img)
                {
                    Bitmap tempImg = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
                }
            }

            j++;
            backgroundWorker4.ReportProgress(j, "");
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        } while (!backgroundWorker4.CancellationPending);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a [double-checked lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).  This prevents the scenario where, in between the null check and the locking, another thread sets `img` to null (ie, a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34510/1001985)).

```
if (img != null)
{
    lock (img)
    {
        if (img != null)
        {
            Bitmap tempImg = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it really work to lock `img` itself, since the value of that variable is being repeatedly changed, or is it actually necessary to (double-)lock *access* to img using some other object like a `readonly object _lock = new object()` or (fast-and-loose) `this`?  And is the lock also required when *setting* img, as well as when reading it?

Comment: @Eric yes you're right, I'm sorry.  You have to use another object for the to lock -- otherwise the lock gets released when a new object is assigned to `img`.

Comment: @Eric and yes, you also want to lock when setting img -- acquiring the lock is what guarantees that the current section will be the only one accessing the variable.